# Bad request when try to sell more than one item

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Hello and thanks in advance for any help. I try several things in order to get this working as well read lot of documentation and follow any sample that I can find. I am sure that I doing something wrong, but can't figure what exactly I am doing wrong.

What I am trying is to implement the PayPal Express Checkout in the [Basic Client Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/) way, and, certainly this work like a charm for a transaction like the below one:

```
{
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": 120,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "details": {
                "tax": 20,
                "subtotal": 100
            }
        },
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Item 1",
                "description": "Item 1 Description",
                "quantity": 1,
                "price": 100,
                "currency": "EUR"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

As I say the above transaction works like expected, however, when I try to add another item into the transaction as in the below one:

```
{
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": 240,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "details": {
                "tax": 20,
                "subtotal": 200
            }
        },
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Item 1",
                "description": "Item 1 Description",
                "quantity": 1,
                "price": 100,
                "currency": "EUR"
            }, {
                "name": "Item 2",
                "description": "Item 2 Description",
                "quantity": 1,
                "price": 100,
                "currency": "EUR"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

... what I get is an error "400 (Bad Request)"... I try several things but any of them appear to work. I simply can't understand what I am doing wrong, since the first transaction works like expected, but, not the second one, even when (to me) the subtotal and total are well calculated with the appropiate tax value in count.

Can anybody help me with this issue? Please, if more information or details are required, just ask for them and I will try to provide it as fast as possible.

Again thanks very much for your help!

P.S. Probably the problem is related with the taxes, since, if I simply remove the tax field and their calculation and just leave the total and subtotals equals, then the transaction is well made also with more than one items. But of course I need to specify the appropiate taxes in the transaction/purchase.

Comment: The obvious thing is that `tax: 20` plus `subtotal: 200` doesn't add up to `total: 240` .. you've doubled everything except the tax!

Comment: Hello! Thanks very much for your reply! I am very sorry, but, I can't understand what you said, probably due to my poor english. Please, let me to explain what I supose. Certainly the subtotal is 200, and the taxes to be applied a 20%, so the total is 240, don't you? Like what I place in the transaction. So what I am doing wrong? Again many thanks for your reply @TripeHound!

Comment: In your second example, you split a total of `240` into tax of `20` and subtotal `200`... these last two only add up to `220`. Presumably, the tax entry should be `40`.  (Or, if going from 200, you calculate 20% of 200 to be 40, so tax should be 40 not 20).

Comment: OMG... I continue without understand very well what you explain @TripeHound, however, I think you point me in the right direction! So, the tax field must be the ammount of the tax... and not the tax percentage, as I am suposing... So please, let me to re-read your answer and try here with this new (to me) concept and then I will post here the results! Many thanks again @TripeHound!

Comment: They works! Many thanks @TripeHound! You got it! Certainly the tax field must contain the total taxes amount (total - subtotal) and not the tax percentage. So that's all! I really appreciate your help @TripeHound, without that probably I can't got the point. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'am a newie here in Stackoverflow so not sure if this is the correct way to "answer a question". The question has been solved by @TrypeHound above. The problem is that I set the tax field of the transaction to be the percentage of the taxes applied. This is not correct. The tax field must reflect the total taxes charged to the purchase, then the total - subtotal. That's the way to do it and certainly now the request works like a charm. Thanks again @TrypeHound for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can see the actual error in the response to the payment request:

[image: PayPal payment request]

Comment: Hello @bluepnume and thanks for your answer. Certainly the API offer more or less good error messages. I think the problem here is I am not read very well the documentation (or maybe my not very good english causes the problem) since I persevere in the error... and that error message never say to us the real answer for the problem: the tax field must be set with the total ammount of the taxes. In other words, if we persevere thinking that the tax field is the tax percentage... then the API errors can't help... because we always get a message like "something is wrong in the request"...